# Ruby HTTPClient check if cookie was sent

Tags: ruby, cookies, httpclient

I am getting a "400 Invalid request method." for the GET request below.
Could that be because I somehow set the cookie (that is demanded by the server) wrong? How can I check that?
What else could it be? (This is for OpenX)

```
url = URI.parse("https://some.domain/path")

cookie = WebAgent::Cookie.new
cookie.name = "some_token"
cookie.value = "some_value"
cookie.url = url

clnt = HTTPClient.new
clnt.cookie_manager.add(cookie)

clnt.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the last line: it should say clnt.put(url) there.

Comment: I updated the code for you. But you are actually able to do it yourself. :)